# Electron: How to handle open commands with multiple Windows users?

Tags: node.js, windows, electron

My Electron app shows files inside their enclosing folder using the standard command `shell.showItemInFolder(fullPath)`. Works.

Now when two Windows users are signed in and they both use the app, the file is always shown on the Windows desktop of the user opened the app first.

In real life, it looks as if the function is broken, but actually the Windows Explorer is simply opened in the other Windows user's session in the background.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in Chrome (using the `Open Containing Folder` button in the Download List window/popup)?

Comment: The problem does not appear in Chrome's download section. Chrome's download section works fine.

Comment: OK, please open an issue at https://github.com/electron/electron/issues

Comment: Done: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7271